# Quickbooks API with VB .NET: This feature is not supported in the specified version of qbXML

Tags: vb.net, quickbooks

We are getting an error when we try and add notes to a customer in Quickbooks.

This feature is not supported in the specified version of qbXML.

We tried getting the latest SDK from here: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0200_quickbooks_desktop/0400_tools/quickbooks_desktop/download_the_sdk

DLL version we are using: 13.0.0.23
Interop.QBFC13.dll

```
Dim custAdd As ICustomerAdd = msgSetRq.AppendCustomerAddRq
custAdd.Notes.SetValue("Test Note")
```

Comment: OK, where's the rest of your code? What version of qbXML are you using? You haven't posted anywhere NEAR enough information or code for us to help you here. Please post the rest of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found the bug. We had to set the version to 13. It was on 2. LOL.

```
msgSetRequest = qbSessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 13, 0)
```